# get value from Json

Tags: php, json

How can I get the amount value in a PHP variable. I have tried below but it does not work

I would be thankful for any help that you guys can give

```
$event_json = json_decode($body);
$event_id = $event_json->id;
$amount = $event_json->data->amount;  


 {
  "created":1326853478,
  "data":{
  "object":{
     "amount":4500,
     "card":{
        "country":"US",
        "cvc_check":"pass",
        "exp_month":7,
        "exp_year":2014,
        "fingerprint":"9aQtfsI8a17zjEZd",
        "id":"cc_00000000000000",
        "last4":"9782",
        "object":"card",
        "type":"Visa"
     },
     "created":1322700852,
     "currency":"usd",
     "disputed":false,
     "fee":0,
     "id":"ch_00000000000000",
     "livemode":false,
     "object":"charge",
     "paid":true,
     "refunded":true
  }
 },
 "id":"evt_00000000000000",
"livemode":false,
"type":"charge.refunded"
 }
```

Comment: When you want an array instead of a object, you can set the second parameter of `json_decode` to `true` :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're just missing the pointer to the `object` object:

```
$amount = $event_json->data->object->amount;
```

Answer (score 1):

`data` has inner element called `object` and `amount` is part of `object` so you may need to use as

```
 $amount =  $event_json->data->object->amount ;
```